# how to count continuous monthly data in series?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, grouping

I have long time series daily data from 1981 to 1991. I have successfully counted the long time monthly zero values in the series by using the code below:

when I tried to count long non zero value in the series by changing the != to == it doesnot work for monthly grouping but it works good for yearly grouping. can anyone help me on this matter?

```
def func(group):
    return (group.prec != 0).astype(int).cumsum().value_counts().values[0] - 1

df.groupby(['year', 'month']).apply(func)
```

(credit: Jianxun Li)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uhh, I see the problem here. `.value_counts()` returns something like below for `compare-cumsum-pattern`

```
3    8
0    5
9    3
6    2
8    1
7    1
4    1
1    1
dtype: int64
```

and `.values[0]` causes confusions because of the integer index. To fix it, use `.iloc[0]` to access the first element.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# simulate some artificial data
# ============================================
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4000), columns=['prec'], index=pd.date_range('1981-01-01', periods=4000, freq='D'))
df['prec'] = np.where(df['prec'] > 0, df['prec'], 0.0)
df['year'] = df.index.year
df['month'] = df.index.month
df['day'] = df.index.day

df
              prec  year  month  day
1981-01-01  1.7641  1981      1    1
1981-01-02  0.4002  1981      1    2
1981-01-03  0.9787  1981      1    3
1981-01-04  2.2409  1981      1    4
1981-01-05  1.8676  1981      1    5
1981-01-06  0.0000  1981      1    6
1981-01-07  0.9501  1981      1    7
1981-01-08  0.0000  1981      1    8
...            ...   ...    ...  ...
1991-12-07  0.0653  1991     12    7
1991-12-08  0.0000  1991     12    8
1991-12-09  0.3949  1991     12    9
1991-12-10  0.0000  1991     12   10
1991-12-11  1.7796  1991     12   11
1991-12-12  0.0000  1991     12   12
1991-12-13  1.5771  1991     12   13
1991-12-14  0.0000  1991     12   14

[4000 rows x 4 columns]



# processing
# ===============================
def func(group):
    return (group.prec == 0).astype(int).cumsum()[group.prec != 0].value_counts().iloc[0]

df.groupby(['year', 'month']).apply(func)

year  month
1981  1         8
      2         3
      3         4
      4        10
      5         5
               ..
1991  8         3
      9         5
      10        3
      11        6
      12        2
dtype: int64


# double check on a particular group
# ======================================================
group = df.groupby(['year', 'month']).get_group((1981,1))
group

              prec  year  month  day
1981-01-01  1.7641  1981      1    1
1981-01-02  0.4002  1981      1    2
1981-01-03  0.9787  1981      1    3
1981-01-04  2.2409  1981      1    4
1981-01-05  1.8676  1981      1    5
1981-01-06  0.0000  1981      1    6
1981-01-07  0.9501  1981      1    7
1981-01-08  0.0000  1981      1    8
1981-01-09  0.0000  1981      1    9
1981-01-10  0.4106  1981      1   10
1981-01-11  0.1440  1981      1   11
1981-01-12  1.4543  1981      1   12
1981-01-13  0.7610  1981      1   13
1981-01-14  0.1217  1981      1   14
1981-01-15  0.4439  1981      1   15
1981-01-16  0.3337  1981      1   16
1981-01-17  1.4941  1981      1   17
1981-01-18  0.0000  1981      1   18
1981-01-19  0.3131  1981      1   19
1981-01-20  0.0000  1981      1   20
1981-01-21  0.0000  1981      1   21
1981-01-22  0.6536  1981      1   22
1981-01-23  0.8644  1981      1   23
1981-01-24  0.0000  1981      1   24
1981-01-25  2.2698  1981      1   25
1981-01-26  0.0000  1981      1   26
1981-01-27  0.0458  1981      1   27
1981-01-28  0.0000  1981      1   28
1981-01-29  1.5328  1981      1   29
1981-01-30  1.4694  1981      1   30
1981-01-31  0.1549  1981      1   31

(group.prec == 0).astype(int).cumsum()[group.prec != 0].value_counts().iloc[0]

# output: 8
```

### Edit:

You need to modify the apply `func` as below to count consecutive non-zero values.

```
def func(group):
    return (group.prec == 0).astype(int).cumsum()[group.prec != 0].value_counts().iloc[0]
```

Comment: so @jianxun Li, what I need to change?

Comment: @bikuser I've highlighted the part of code to be modified. You can test it on your sample data and it should run properly. Let me know if that's not the case.

Comment: you mean to remove .value_counts() in def function:

Comment: @bikuser No, just replace the `def func` with the one shown in `Edit` part of my post.

Comment: yes I used this function..its work perfectly for yearly grouping and show the exact value..but when I grouped by yearly and monthly then it does not work and showed the max non zero value in other year

Comment: @bikuser you mean `df.groupby(['year']).apply(func)` does work, but `df.groupby(['year', 'month']).apply(func)` doesn't? I cannot see any reason why this happens. Could you provide an example to reproduce the incorrect result you saw? Or if your data is not proprietary, can you upload your sample data via dropbox sharelink or google driver?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2rkXkOkG7ExYVhkb3lyc0c3UjA/view?usp=sharing                             you can see my data in this link when when you run by df.groupby(['year']).apply(func) then you will  get the max in 1989 and if you run df.groupby(['year', 'month']).apply(func) then you will get the different value in 1983 ..strange na

Comment: @bikuser The issue arises because the long consecutive series could span over two months, for example `1988-01-21` - `1988-02-12`, so if you group by year, it gives you `23` days, but if you group by month, it gives you `11` and `12` in Jan and Feb separately.

Comment: so is there any ways to solve this problem i am tired of this :(

Comment: @bikuser that's not the problem of the code, but the programming logic. Do you want to count longest consecutive series for each year OR each month? These two will give you different results.

Comment: i think it would be better to count for each month

Comment: @bikuser then just use `df.groupby(['year', 'month']).apply(func)` and you should be fine. :-)